# Magento2 error Property TriggerReload does not have accessor method getTriggerReload

Tags: magento2

I am using below link code but getting following error, the link code is use to update shipping method after coupon code is applied

https://alanstorm.com/refresh-shipping-rates-for-the-magento-2-checkout/

I am getting following error

[image]

According, to me it is due to

```
//address.trigger_reload = new Date().getTime();
```

Comment: We had same issue with this on 2.2.6 version

Cant say for sure why this is happening, but we ended up removing this line

`address.trigger_reload = new Date().getTime();`

For us everything else worked fine without this line that supposed to trick magento into thinking that address has changed.

Comment: where in the magento vendor files is that reference to the `address.trigger_reload = new Date().getTime();` ?

Answer (score 1):

i resolve this error with this code:

```
requirejs([
                        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
                        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry'
                 ], function (quote, rateRegistry) {
                        var address = quote.shippingAddress();                          
                        rateRegistry.set(address.getKey(), null);
                        rateRegistry.set(address.getCacheKey(), null);
                        quote.shippingAddress(address);
                        quote.paymentMethod(paymentMethod);
                        address.trigger_reload = new Date().getTime();
                 });
```